# Исследование таймеров TCP

Tags: tcp-ip

Есть задача провести исследование алгоритмов управления таймерами в протоколе TCP. Собственно с теоретической части вопроса проблем не возникает.. а вот как с практической стороны к этому подойти.. неделя поисков в интернете и чтения книг ни к чему не привели... Хотелось бы конечно обойтись малыми жертвами и с помощью какой-нить утилиты поменять параметры таймеров и посмотреть, как эти параметры влияют на скорость передачи данных, при каких условиях пакетов теряется меньше и т.д. так же можно было бы копнуть в сторону моделирования сетей, здесь я нашел только network simulator, но в его api про эти самые таймеры упоминания не нашёл.

Comment: Который network simulator? Про таймеры там вряд ли написано, но вот про логику работы узлов... Так что вопрос, какой simulator Вы нашли?

Comment: network simulator 3. http://www.nsnam.org/